# Websockets and database object scope

Tags: node.js, postgresql, autobahn

In my code below I wish to receive an "order" from the feed and store it in the database.

I understand that the class method marketEvent will be called whenever data is received and accordingly I would need my insert statement within this function.

It would be inefficient to open and close the db connection each time the class method is called so I seek to open the connection and pass the db object through to marketEvent.

I am new to nodejs and web sockets so can't work out how to put it together.

```
var pg = require("pg")
var conString = "postgres://myusername:mypassword@localhost/poloniex";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);


var autobahn = require('autobahn');
var wsuri = "wss://api.poloniex.com";
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
    url: wsuri,
    realm: "realm1"
});

connection.onopen = function (session) {
    function marketEvent (args,kwargs) {
        client.query("INSERT INTO orderbook(order) values($1)", [args]);
    }
    session.subscribe('BTC_XMR', marketEvent);

}

connection.onclose = function () {
    console.log("Websocket connection closed");
}


client.connect();
connection.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of "pg" and "autobahn" both. But from the documentation of "pg" package, may I offer you a hint of solution

**client.connect()** is not meant to be an isolated call. It expects a function delegate to carry out the operation.

```
connection.onopen = function (session) {
    function marketEvent (args,kwargs) {
        client.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            client.query("INSERT ...", [args]);
        });
    }
    session.subscribe('BTC_XMR', marketEvent);

}
```

About using the connection efficiently, you may be asking for pooling I guess.

```
var pool = new pg.Pool(config);
pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
    if (err) throw err;
    client.query('INSERT ...', function(err, result) {
        //call `done()` to release the client back to the pool 
        done();
    });
});
```

Please refer original source of this suggestion for the exact usage:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg